# Lyrics for Haşim & Gülistan Tokdemir - Şirinamın

Tags: lyrics

Could anyone help me out with the lyrics for this [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QJLhc7WHmo). An English translation would be amazing but Kurdish lyrics are also okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Şîrîna min, şîrîna min,
Xweş newe<sup>1</sup> vê birina min,
Destê xwe bide destê min,
Destê xwe bide destê min,
Ne bîre min, min ra nema,
Destê xwe bide destê min,
Destê xwe bide destê min,
Ne bîre min, min ra nema.

Berjêr mere<sup>2</sup>, berjêr çî ma,
Çîyaye bilindê, rîye xemê,
Berjêr mere<sup>2</sup>, berjê çî ma,
Çîyaye bilindê, rîye xemê,
Were rindê, ku dêr herrê,
Were rindê, ku dêr herrê,
Dîne rûnê, yarê te me,
Were rindê, ku dêr herrê,
Were rindê, ku dêr herrê,
Dîne rûnê, yarê te me.

Malê me li hember hevda,
Te ser xanî bilxur tevda,
Malê me li hember hevda,
Te ser xanî bilxur tevda,
Bira, bavê...
Bira, bavê...
Xwînê me bi çenawe hevda,
Bira, bavê tem bikuşt ne,
Bira, bavê tem bikuşt ne,
Xwînê me bi çenawe hevda.

Ro<sup>3</sup> bilind bû.. ?,
?, were li vir,

Eger dilê te li min tine,
Eger dilê te li min tine,
Ez bim xangê, tu bi bira,
Eger dilê te li min tine,
Eger dilê te li min tine,
Hevra bine xwişk û bira.

1. 'nabe' in standard Kurmanji
2. 'nere' in standard Kurmanji
3. 'roj' in standard Kurmanji

---

Thanks to Kurdê Dîn who helped me on [lyrics translate](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/g%C3%BClistan-tokdemir-%C5%9Firina-min-lyrics.html).