# Lyrics for the song "Dariya" performed by Niyaz Nawab

Tags: lyrics

Please help me out with Romanized phonetic transcription of **[this song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n6JlpdG7r0w)**, based on poetry of Hafez, sung by Niyaz Nawab. I do not know to read Persian language.

What I have tried before:

1. I tried to Google the lyrics with keywords "Dideh Darya Konam". It gives me a Persian script sung by some other singer. then I romanized it with [farsi romanization](https://mylanguages.org/farsi_romanization.php) and [cleanup](https://mylanguages.org/romanization_cleanup.php) tools respectively, which are offered by   "My Languages ORG". Still that romanization did not seem to match on many places with the Niyaz Nawab singing video.
2. I have tried to read the lyrics given in [spotify](https://open.spotify.com/track/2HP07sKpL7gyWjeMoq0PcX?flow_ctx=59d412e6-bebf-4ab8-a0ab-6401c02e5e09%3A1702842939) , but this was not selectable or searcheable. I could not read it. I have added a screenshot that I took from Spotify.

[image: Spotify Screenshot]

Therefore I pray to provide me a Romanized phonetic transcription of this song.
Regards.

P.S. I have saw [this kind of question](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/8165/lyrics-for-ha%C5%9Fim-g%C3%BClistan-tokdemir-%C5%9Eirinam%C4%B1n) being asked in this site, so therefore I thought this site is appropriate for this question.

Comment: Your problem is not that you need the lyrics, you've been able to find them. Your problem is you need a Persian to Latin-characters converter. [Something along these lines](https://mylanguages.org/persian_romanization.php), perhaps?

Comment: @Mast does not matter because I already have that tool, and the Spotify text cannot be copied with mouse pointer.

Comment: @Mast The problem is I still need the lyrics (in a form that I am able to read). And since I cannot copy the text using mouse pointer, there is no way I can put the text into that tool.  Therefore manually writing the lyrics in romanized form is what I was looking for. Regards.